# How do I make the optimizer to properly put variables into registers?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, optimization

I have a simple function that takes two variables by reference:

```
void foo(int*& it2,
         bit_reader<big_endian_tag>& reader2)
{
    for(/* ... */)
    {
        *it2++ = boo(reader2.next());
        // it2++ => 0x14001d890 add qword ptr [r12], 0x4
    }
}
```

The problem here is that for `it2` and `reader2` the optimizer makes the computer write to memory instead of registers during the loop.

However, the following code puts the variables properly into registers during the loop, but has an extra overhead in the form of unnecessary copies, before and after the loop:

```
void foo2(int*& it2,
         bit_reader<big_endian_tag>& reader2)
{
    auto reader = reader2;
    auto it     = it2;

    for(/* ... */)
    {
        *it++ = boo(reader.next());
        // it++ => 0x14001d890 add r15, 0x4
    }

    reader2 = reader;
    it2 = it;
}
```

e.g.

How can I make the first example generate the same code as the second example but without the extra copies?

Comment: How do you expect to change `it2` and `reader2` without writing to the memory where they are stored?

Comment: I would expect the compiler to keep `it2` and `reader2` in registers while the loop is running and only write them back into memory at the end of the loop.

Comment: It theoretically *could*, if it could also prove that `boo(reader.next())` can never, ever be affected by the updated values.

Comment: I actually expect the writes to go to L1 cache, which in this case (no store-load dependency) might be just as fast as a register.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the compiler cannot prove `it2` does not change within the function. (Well, it could, but that's vastly beyond the intended capabilities of a normal C++ compiler.)

How does it know `boo(reader2.next());` doesn't change the value? Consider:

```
int* i = 0;

struct foo
{
    int myInt;
    int blah() { i = &myInt; return 5; }
};

void bar(int*& ptr, const foo& f)
{
    *ptr = f.blah(); // changes value of ptr!
}

int otherInt;
i = &otherInt;

bar(i, foo());
```

This does not assign anything to `otherInt`, whereas after your transformation it would:

```
void bar(int*& ptr, const foo& f)
{
    int* ptrCopy = ptr;
    *ptrCopy = f.blah(); // changes ptr, but not ptrCopy
}
```

So unless the compiler can prove the behavior is the same, it cannot make the optimization.

C99 solves this problem with the `restrict` keyword, but C++ has no equivalent. There are extensions that exist in most C++ compilers though, such as `__restrict__` or `__restrict`.

To do it in standard C++, you just have to be explicit and make the copy yourself

Comment: I tried passing them as pointer and using __restrict, however that made no difference. I guess doing the copies explicitly is the best way.

Comment: @ronag: Hm, I've never actually used it myself so I can't be of much help there. :( If your code can be simplified into a self-contained and compileable example, I would recommend you ask a second question.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you cannot.

When you pass the parameters by non-const reference, you ask the compiler to update the original variables. So it *has to* write the new values to memory.

Comment: I understand that, but it doesn't have to write to memory in every loop iteration, only at the end of the loop, as I am doing in my second example.

Comment: The compiler must be able to realize that. The expression `*it2++ = boo(reader2.next());` is really hard for the compiler to analyze, so most don't care to cache values that *might* be visible from the outside.

Answer (score 0):

It is all about optimizing for the "memory hierarchies", doing computation is fastest when done directly on registers and that's why you really really want to take stuff from memory and copy it into registers **before** computing anything on it and then copy the result back into the memory location you need to. The performance you gain by computing directly on registers will generally offset the cost of loading and saving the memory to and from registers.

How do you ensure you get stuff from memory into registers? e.g.

```
size_t size;
double* arr;
for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; ++i) {
    double a = arr[i];     // copy to register
    double b = arr[i + 1]; // copy to register
    b = a*b + b;           // make sure flop computation is done in registers
    arr[i] = b;            // copy back to memory
}
```